# Button inside modal dialog is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a grid with view buttons. When you click the view button a modal dialog opens and displays all the information in a form.

I also have a button (buttonID:Button1) inside my modal dialog. The problem is that when I click on the button inside the dialog nothing happens.

This is what I have so far:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddUser.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddUser" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.4.5/js/bootstrapvalidator.min.js'></script>
    <link href ="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-Lightnes/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>

    <script>
        function popup(idn, un, ps, em) {
            $("#userid").text(idn);
            $("#usern").text(un);
            $("#pwd").text(ps);
            $("#eml").text(em);
            $("#popupdiv").dialog({
                closeOnEscape: false,
                position: 'fixed',
                width: 1080,
                height: 500,
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                },
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server" >

            <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" runat="server" Text="Add New User" OnClick="btnAddUser_Click" />
            <asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="gvUsers" runat="server"  PagerStyle-CssClass="pager"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows"         
                CssClass="mydatagrid" AllowPaging="True" 
                ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" />
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="Password" HeaderText="Password" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img src="images/edit.png" id="imgBtn" style="width:20px; height:20px" onclick='popup("<%# Eval("UserID") %>", "<%# Eval("Username") %>","<%# Eval("Password") %>","<%# Eval("Email") %>")'></>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        <div class="container"> 
            <div id="popupdiv" style=" margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
     background-color: #333333;
    background-color: #333333; ">
                <div class="well form-horizontal"   id="contact_form">
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <textarea id="userid" runat="server" style="width:250px; height:35px; resize: none" name="first_name"  class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Password</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
   <textarea type="text" id="usern"  runat="server" style="width:250px; height:35px; resize: none" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
               <textarea type="text" id="pwd"  runat="server" style="width:250px; height:35px; resize: none" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->

<div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Role</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
            <textarea type="text" id="eml"  runat="server" style="width:250px; height:35px; resize: none" class="form-control" ></textarea>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click1"/>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>



        </div>
                </div>
</div>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Code for my button functionality but it does not work

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/AddNewUser.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Switch to a LinkButton and it will work again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`UseSubmitBehavior="false"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) in button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-warning" runat="server"
    Text="Submit" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="Button1_Click1"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir!!
May you please provide a little more information on why it wasn't working before and why it is working now (obviously now I added UseSubmitBehavior="false") so that I can understand better

Comment: The value of the UseSubmitBehavior property
    is false. Therefore the button uses the ASP.NET 
    postback mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that the modal is being created **outside** the form, so if the button is created outside the form it won't work.

Most modals have a way to set where the modal will be created. For instance, `jquery-ui` has the [appendTo](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo) property. So, if you set `appendTo: 'FORM'` it will create the modal inside the form and your button will work as expected.

Comment: I can confirm the button is part of the form. You can check my code above for further reference

Comment: I think the problem is that I am not adding or calling the button onClick method inside my JS

Comment: Can you confirm that the button is part of the form in the browser while the popup is open? You might have created the modal inside the form but when  the modal dialog is opened it might be appened to the body instead of the form.

Comment: If you are using jquery-ui, the default value there is "body" http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo

Comment: I am trying to call the onClick method inside my JS but it still does nothing. However, when i I say alert(); it responds within the modal dialog but when i call the onClick it does nothing